# Polynomial approximation (with decreasing error preferably) of Bessel functions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, bessel-functions

The functions: $$J_1(a\sqrt x) = ?? $$
$$I_1(a\sqrt x) = ?? $$
s.t. $$a, \sqrt x \in R $$

See the first answer to a question I've asked previously for an example of what I'd be looking for.

[Please provide a function approximating the following hypergeometric series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3222763/322359)

Comment: Are you looking for approximations for small or large values of the argument ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Large values of the argument, and any domain exceptions.  Positive numbers preferred, will take answers about negative numbers too.